# Задание по среднему возрасту в таблице и сколько на каждую неделю дней рождений. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, у меня есть практическое задание на курсах, но я не понимаю как его выполнить.

> 1)Подсчитайте средний возраст пользователей в таблице users.
> 2)Подсчитайте количество дней рождения, которые приходятся на каждый
> из дней недели. Следует учесть, что необходимы дни недели текущего
> года, а не года рождения.

Вот данные таблицы, чтобы было проще:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне говорили что-то про виртуальные таблицы, но до меня не дошло.
Так же знаю что можно `datetime((to_days(now()) - to_days(birthday)) / 365.25)` - чтобы узнать сколько лет персоне, но дальше этого не идет(( Помогите пожалуйста, как можно было понять, это MySQL.

Вот с подсказкой в комментарии, все еще не понимаю как?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое сделано так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Функция AVG(). 2) GROUP BY, WEEKDAY() и COUNT()/SUM().

Comment: Так или как? mysql> insert into `users` (`middle_age`) values(avg((to_days(now()) - to_days(birthday)) / 365.25);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: не надо заморачиваться с вычислением точного возраста. когда вы подсчитаете средний среди записей округлите до целого все эти попытки вычислить точное значение пропадут. берите просто разницу между датами в годах. Вам ведь вряд ли нужен средний возраст вида `35.7489304` года, правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я эту же домашку сейчас делаю.
Получилось через count & group by.

1)

```
select
      avg(
         (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday)) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m%d')) 
          )
 FROM profiles
```

2. 

```
select 
    weekday(date_format(birthday, '2021-%m-%d')) as 'day_number',
    count(*) as 'birthdays_qnty'
from profiles
group by weekday(date_format(birthday, '2021-%m-%d'))
order by day_number;
```

Comment: спаситель просто, спасибо большое!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: хотя у меня есть дни рождения которые приходяться на null день, странно